# which config file is openssh sshd using?

Tags: linux-mint, sshd

Where can i check/verify which config file sshd is using? I know you can change the config file to use by using `-f` command, but is there a way to echo which config file is currently being used or is there a file I can view to check this?

Comment: If there is no `-f` in `sshd`'s command line then it is the default file. Is that not enough for you? Do you want to be able to detect whether your `sshd` has be compiled with different defaults? You may run `sshd` through `strace`: `strace -o /root/sshd.strace -e trace=file sshd ...`

Comment: what do you mean by if there is no `-f` in `sshd`'s command line? for my question, say i want to debug a couple configs files and i go back and forth, how could i view which config file sshd is currently using?

Comment: Check the `sshd` process command line: `pgrep -fa sshd` or `pgrep -fl sshd`. If it doesn't have a `-f`, then it's the default, for which you can use `strace`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @Hauke Laging's comment. When you run `strace` on the `sshd` binary it outputs debugging information on how the program starts and what files it tries to access. From which we can use `grep` to list the /etc/ files which it tries to access.

```
$ sudo strace -e trace=file /usr/sbin/sshd |& grep '^open('|grep '/etc/'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/etc/ssh/sshd_config", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/etc/gai.conf", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/etc/ssh/blacklist.ECDSA-256", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

From the above `strace` output `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is used as `ssh` configuration.

Comment: "When you run strace on the sshd binary it outputs debugging information on how the program starts and what files it tries to access." That's not really accurate. `strace` outputs the system calls made by the traced program. In particular, with the `-e trace=file` the ones which involve file manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given:

1. Debug mode might be helpful:
   `[root@ip-10-41-162-92 ~]# /usr/sbin/sshd -df /etc/ssh/sshd_config.test
   debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.7, OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
   ...
   debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
   debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-df'
   debug1: rexec_argv[2]='/etc/ssh/sshd_config.test'
   ...`

The output tells what file was used (if -f flag was given).

2. Pretty obvious but still, if you're debugging configuration, remember that stderr is printed to /var/log/messages when running sshd, so errors like
   `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 91: Unsupported option GSSAPIAuthentication
   /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 93: Unsupported option GSSAPICleanupCredentials`

   tell which file you're using